# Cannot connect to MongoDB when I specify database name

Tags: mongodb, docker, security

I run MongoDB docker container on my local computer and when I try to connect to MongoDB container without specifying database name, it works fine.
With following command, I managed to connect to MongoDB.

```
$ mongo "mongodb://username@127.0.0.1:27017"
```

But when I try to connect with database name, it will return following error.

```
$ mongo "mongodb://username@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname"

MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbname?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-02-25T00:26:09.511+0900 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2021-02-25T00:26:09.515+0900 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2021-02-25T00:26:09.515+0900 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I thought it might be because database doesn't exist yet, so I tried with database which already exist but same result.

And this is my local environment.
MacOS version 11.2.1
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
mongo official docker image version 4.0.4

Comment: `Error: Authentication failed.` - thats the error. Try using the authenticationDatabase option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you! I added `?authSource=admin` and it works! Can you please post an answer so I can accept it

Comment: I think it's OK when you upvote the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add your password right after the username string, if you dont have a password leave the username out of the connectionstring.

**With password**

mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname

**Without password**

mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname

Comment: I already have tried it too but didn't work :(